# O(1) vs local variable

Tags: java, performance, dictionary, data-structures, coding-style

I have a map with strings: `Map<String, Boolean> myMap;`
I use it few times to check a condition:
`if (myMap.get("isDebug")) ...` which has O(1) time complexity.
Is extracting this to variable in the beginning of a program can boost performance, or in other words is not extracting it to a variable in the beginning of the program is a performance **hit**?

Comment: Yes, local variables and also instance fields are definitely faster than a `Map`.  Don't over optimize your code though before you have a chance to profile it.

Comment: How many times do you check that condition? Millions of times? If not, don't bother with such micro optimization.

Comment: As you already know, typically `map.get("isDebug")` is very fast and normally not worth worrying about. Whether the small amount of time it takes matters depends on the behaviour and requirements of your program. Unless it makes an observable difference, it's not worth worrying about. However, if adding a variable makes your code more readable or maintainable, then that is a good reason to do it.

Comment: Can it be changed in between checks? If it can, do you want one of the debug-only things to execute, but not the next? Or once one debug-only action occurs (or does not), do you want to do the same for all actions until you are finished? This is a question of correctness, far more important than any performance difference.

Comment: Beware of premature optimization. Such small optimizations should only be considered if you are actually experiencing performance problems and your analysis indicates it's in the map access. I would do it for another reason, though: readability.

Comment: thanks all for your inputs. this called about 3-4 times. i also feel that it does not worth the optimization.